# Python code executes from interpreter but not from Windows Command Prompt

Tags: python

I made a program, stored in a folder in `C:/Python27` where I keep the `python.exe` file. In this program I do some I/O to and from files. When I run the file in the interpreter like this:

```
myProgram.function("C:/Pyhton27/data")
```

it works fine.

When I try in the command prompt (`cmd.exe`) I set up my path, then I do:

```
C:/Python27/python C:/Python27/myProgram C:/Python27/data
```

I don't get any error messages and the program returns the print messages saying everything went fine. But there is no new output to the file when I change the data.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You will need to be more specific, ideally by showing your code.

Comment: My best guess without seeing something is that you haven't set your script up properly to be run with command line arguments. So it runs and does nothing.

Comment: I suspect the path separators. Try running like this to confirm: python myProgram data. Hopefully the Pyhton27 is a typo here and not in the code.

Comment: The thing is, I know it both starts the program, and at least checks the file location, because if I put something that isn't a file I get an error. And yes, it was a typo here, not in my call. When I do the call everything seems to go fine, except it doesn't actually write to a file, which is does if I call it from the interpreter.

Comment: I'm guessing again. Different permissions in the two scenarios? Is the file being closed in the case where it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes it might be! Could you elaborate what my issue is?

Comment: @user1748963 can you post some code that works or doesn't

Comment: What is the current directory when you run it? Try `cd \Python27 && python myProgram data`